# How can I change the bullet symbol on an unordered list?

Tags: lists, itemize, bullets

I'm in a class where homework has to be submited using LaTeX, for the first homework they are teaching LaTeX by making us transcribe a PDF document. I'm pretty much all-set but I cannot find an answer for this, see, in the following list they use different bullet symbols for each items:

[image: list i want to create]

I hope someone has the answer on this, thanks in advancement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
Here is text before the itemize\\
and now for the itemize
\begin{itemize}
\item[\ding{168}] And we begin
\item[$\diamondsuit$] Here is text
\item[$\heartsuit$] blah blah
\item[\ding{171}] Sandia
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks! This worked. Just a little issue, the character number 171 isn't exactly the same as in the reference document but let's hope they aren't that strict with that!

Comment: @PedroPapel See documentation link at https://ctan.org/pkg/pifont.  Page 7 shows solid spade as slot 171.